# How do I know if the user has clicked on a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

What is the easiest way to determine which button was clicked by the user?

What I am doing:

```
 if((themeSeclection.highlighted = YES)){
        informationView.text =@"This is test";
    }
    if((caputreImage.highlighted = YES)){
        informationView.text =@"This is another test";
    }
    if((switchCamera.highlighted = YES)){
        informationView.text =@"Test 3";
    }
```

Comment: Either have a different action selector for each button or look at the `sender` parameter that is passed to the action which contains the button that was pressed

Comment: You need to have an action method defined for those buttons.

Comment: why was this posted down voted ?!

Answer (score 1):

You have got your buttons as `IBOutlets` or just locally created

```
UIButton *btn1;
UIButton *btn2;
UIButton *btn3;
```

Now you have the option to assign individual methods as actions to these buttons. However, one action would to, which may be the following:

```
- (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if (sender == btn1) ...
    if (sender == btn2) ... 
    // and so on
}
```

Credits go to dan. :-)

Comment: thanks allot for your answer but hmm it does not work correctly the if statement is never true..